# Ignore transparent image

Tags: html, css

i need to make an transparent image that goes through all web content to be ignored by other functions such as nav bar.

```
<div id="birds">
<img src="birds.png" class="cover">
</div>
#birds{
position: relative;
}


#birds img.cover{
position: absolute;
float:right;
margin-left: 4.8%;

}
```

Comment: Whatchoo talkin 'bout, Willis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are after, but if I was to take a guess, it would be `pointer-events: none;`

Unfortunately this doesn't currently work in Internet Explorer or Opera though.

Comment: yes that's exactly what i was looking just sad point that its not working for opera and ie , but thnx anyway:)